# react-native-maps MapView WMS without tile

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps, wms

Is it possible to use WMS standard layer with react-native-maps MapView without tiling the response. I currently have:

```
   <View style={mapsStyles.container}>
    <MapView
      provider={this.props.provider}
      //mapType={MAP_TYPES.SATELLITE}
      style={mapsStyles.map}
      customMapStyle={MapStyle}
      initialRegion={region}
    >
      <WMSTile
        urlTemplate={wms.apiUrl + '/wms?service=' + wms.service + '&version=' + wms.version + '&request=' + wms.request + '&format=' + wms.format + '&transparent=' + wms.transparent + '&layers=' + wms.layers + '&time=' + wms.time + '&width=' + wms.wmsWidth + '&height=' + wms.wmsHeight + '&CRS=' + wms.crs + '&styles=' + wms.styles + '&bbox=' + wms.bbox}
        zIndex={1}
        opacity={0.5}
        tileSize={512}
        epsgSpec={'EPSG:4326'}
      />
    </MapView>
  </View>
```

.. but I would like to have the response handled tiled=false as a one image.

Comment: Did you have any luck? Stuck in the same thing